# Python - Get group names from aggregated results in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   minute   values
0   1        3
1   2        4
2   1        1
3   4        6
4   3        7
5   2        2
```

When I apply

```
df.groupby('minute').sum().sort('values', ascending=False)
```

This gives:

```
         values
minute
3        7
2        6
4        6
1        4
```

I want to get first two values in minute column in an array like [3,2]. How can I access values in minute column

Comment: Are you looking for `grouped = df.groupby('minute').sum().sort('values', ascending=False); grouped.index[:2]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is the values from the minute column in the grouped dataframe (which would be the index column as well) , you can use `DataFrame.index` , to access that column. Example -

```
grouped = df.groupby('minute').sum().sort('values', ascending=False)
grouped.index[:2]
```

If you really want it as a list, you can use `.tolist()` to convert it to a list. Example -

```
grouped.index[:2].tolist()
```

Demo -

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   minute  values
0       1       3
1       2       4
2       1       1
3       4       6
4       3       7
5       2       2

In [4]: grouped = df.groupby('minute').sum().sort('values', ascending=False)

In [5]: grouped.index[:2]
Out[5]: Int64Index([3, 2], dtype='int64', name='minute')

In [6]: grouped.index[:2].tolist()
Out[6]: [3, 2]
```